# Environmental config in TestNG

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testng

I have a requirement where i have to 2 environment. Test and Production.

I need to have a single 'testng' xml file where i have to change a single parameter like "env". Depends on Test or Production env value, the respective parameters have to taken and start running the test scripts.

How can i achieve this in 'testng'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. If you have 2 different environments with different parameters for the same tests, you need 2 "testng" xml files.

You can avoid duplication with the `<suite-files>` node but you'll have to create 3 'testng' xml files.